# Return multiple documents which match the latest date with a single MongoDB query in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

The following is MongoDB query. What is the best possible way to write this query in Mongoose?

```
db.logs.find({date: db.logs.find({}, {date:1,"_id":0}).sort({date:-1}).limit(1).toArray()[0].date})
```

There could be multiple documents  with the same date and we need to retrieve all the documents that match the latest date.

Comment: There are 2 queries.

Comment: @chridam, using your query it will return only 1 record. But if there are multiple documents having the latest date it will pick only 1 and ignore others. This should not happen

Comment: what is the trouble in these queries ? `const date = await db.logs.find({ }, { date: 1, _id: false }).sort({ date: -1 }).limit(1)` and then 
`const data = await db.logs.find({ date: date[0].date })`

Answer (score 2):

The aggregation framework makes it possible to write this in a single query. You would require a pipeline that has an initial **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)** operator to do a self-join and within the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)** execute a pipeline on the joined collection which allows for uncorrelated sub-queries to return the latest date:

```
db.logs.aggregate([
    {  "$lookup": {
        "from": "logs",
        "pipeline": [
            { "$sort": { "date": -1 } },
            { "$limit": 1 },
            { "$project": { "_id": 0, "date": 1 } }
        ],
        "as": "latest"
    } }
])
```

A further step is required to reshape the new field latest produced above so that the array is flattened. Use **[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/)** to reshape and **[`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/)** to flatten the array or use **[`"$unwind"`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)**:

```
db.logs.aggregate([
    {  "$lookup": {
        "from": "logs",
        "pipeline": [
            { "$sort": { "date": -1 } },
            { "$limit": 1 },
            { "$project": { "_id": 0, "date": 1 } }
        ],
        "as": "latest"
    } },
    { "$addFields": { "latest": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$latest", 0] } } }
])
```

The final step would be to filter the documents in the resulting pipeline using **[`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/)** in a **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** stage since you will be comparing fields from the same document:

```
db.logs.aggregate([
    {  "$lookup": {
        "from": "logs",
        "pipeline": [
            { "$sort": { "date": -1 } },
            { "$limit": 1 },
            { "$project": { "_id": 0, "date": 1 } }
        ],
        "as": "latest"
    } },
    { "$addFields": { "latest": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$latest", 0] } } },
    { "$match": {
        "$expr": {
            "$eq": [ "$date", "$latest.date" ]
        } 
    } }
])
```

Getting the query into Mongoose becomes a trivial exercise.